# JavaScript отсортировать часть объектов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, angularjs, сортировка, объекты

Всем доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь с сортировкой массива объектов с дополнительным условием.
Например, есть массив объектов:

```
var objs = [ 
{ first_name: 'Jogn', last_name: 'Smith', status: 'A'     },
{ first_name: 'Brian',    last_name: 'Fox', status: 'B'   },
{ first_name: 'Pit', last_name: 'Stop', status 'B' },
{ first_name: 'Mark', last_name: 'Ford', status 'A' },
{ first_name: 'Stan', last_name: 'Lork', status 'C' }
];
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все элементы, которые имеют status со значением 'А' всегда были в начале списка, независимо от того, как идет сортировка по возрастанию или убыванию. То есть, они не должны включаться в сортировку и просто всегда находиться вверху списка.
Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var objs = [ 
  { first_name: 'Jogn', last_name: 'Smith', status: 'A' },
  { first_name: 'Brian', last_name: 'Fox', status: 'B' },
  { first_name: 'Pit', last_name: 'Stop', status: 'B' },
  { first_name: 'Mark', last_name: 'Ford', status: 'A' },
  { first_name: "Stan", last_name: "Lork", status: 'C' }
];

objs.sort((a, b) => {
  if ((a.status == 'A' && b.status == 'A') ||
      (a.status != 'A' && b.status != 'A')) {
      // дополнительные условия
  } else {
    return (a.status == 'A')? -1 : 1;
  }
});

console.log(objs);
```