# Десереализация xml файла не инициализирует поля класса

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, десериализация

Дорброго времени суток!
При попытке загрузить xml файл на сервер и преобразовать его в объект - создается объект с пустыми полями класса.

xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <name>Book 3</name>
    <author>Author 3</author>
    <price>3200</price>
    <id>547</id>
  </book>
</books>
```

Класс:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("books")]
    public class Book {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Athor")]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Price")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Код десериализации:

```
private void UploadViaXmlSerializer(HttpRequestBase request) {
            for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFileBase fileData = request.Files[i];

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
                using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(fileData.InputStream)) {
                    Book book = (Book)serializer.Deserialize(fs); //book имеет поля со значениями null и 0
                }
            }
        }
```

Также буду очень признателен, если подскажете или поделитесь ссылкой на источник, где сказано, как десереализовать файл с множеством элементов.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916613/javascript-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0

Answer (score 3):

```
    [XmlElement("name")] // "N" -> "n" и т.д.
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, но, к сожалению, это не решило проблему. Видимо где-то еще есть ошибка. Может в классе нужно дополнительно какие-то атрибуты указать - связанные с неймспейсом, схемой или чем-то подобным? Сам в этой теме только разбираюсь и пока не нашел нужного мне ответа.